# Sum of columns from two tables even if value doesn't match?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

The following query that uses an inner join returns the sum where `name` matches in both tables.

```
;with cte1 as
(
    select 'a' as 'name', 1 as 'total'
    union
    select 'b', 2
    union
    select 'x', 6
    union
    select 'y', 7
    union
    select 'z', 8
    union
    select 'f', 30
),
cte2 as
(
    select 'a' as 'name', 11 as 'total'
    union
    select 'b', 22
    union
    select 'd', 6
    union
    select 'y', 7
    union
    select 'z', 8
)
select cte1.name, cte1.total + cte2.total as 'total'
from cte1 inner join cte2 on
cte1.name = cte2.name
```

The result is:

```
name    total   total   total
a       1       11      12
b       2       22      24
y       7       7       14
z       8       8       16
```

I need to also display the totals even if there's no match, so the result should look like below (*"n/a"* is just to display that a value does not exist in the cte):

```
name    cte1.total  cte2.total  total
a       1           11          12
b       2           22          24
y       7           7           14
z       8           8           16
f       30          n/a         30
x       6           n/a         6
d       n/a         6           6
```

Values 'x' and 'f' are not in cte2, but they're included in the total. 'd' is not in cte1, but we also see a total.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following using a [full outer join](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-full-outer-join/) eg

```sql
;with cte1 as
(
    select 'a' as 'name', 1 as 'total'
    union
    select 'b', 2
    union
    select 'x', 6
    union
    select 'y', 7
    union
    select 'z', 8
    union
    select 'f', 30
),
cte2 as
(
    select 'a' as 'name', 11 as 'total'
    union
    select 'b', 22
    union
    select 'd', 6
    union
    select 'y', 7
    union
    select 'z', 8
)
select 
    coalesce(cte1.name,cte2.name) as name, 
    cte1.total as cte1total , 
    cte2.total as cte2total, 
    coalesce(cte1.total,0) + coalesce(cte2.total,0) as 'total'
from cte1 full outer join cte2 on
cte1.name = cte2.name
```

[View working demo db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3b1f934e764a65a04ab1d2359ca35714)

| name | cte1total | cte2total | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 11 | 12 |
| b | 2 | 22 | 24 |
| f | 30 |  | 30 |
| x | 6 |  | 6 |
| y | 7 | 7 | 14 |
| z | 8 | 8 | 16 |
| d |  | 6 | 6 |

Answer (score 0):

Just another option is a conditional aggregation in concert with a Union ALL

**Example**

```
 Select Name
       ,Total1 = sum( case when Src=1 then Total end)
       ,Total2 = sum( case when Src=2 then Total end)  
       ,Total  = sum( Total )
 From  (
         Select *,Src = 1 from cte1
         Union All
         Select *,Src = 2 from cte2   -- Easy to Expand if necessary
       ) A
 Group By Name
```

**Results**

[image]